# Problems after upgrade to Fedora 24 on Thinkpad T460

Tags: fedora, upgrade

I am having two major problems after updating to Fedora 24 from 23 on a thinkpad T460:

1. On boot it will freeze with the line `Probing EDD (edd=off to disable)`. This happens with the 4.5.7 and 4.6.3 kernel. It does not happen with the 4.5.3 kernel. To make things even more interesting, this problem only appears when running on battery power.
2. xbacklight stopped working. The folder /sys/class/backlight... is still there and I can manually change the backlight, but xbacklight just says 
   `No outputs have backlight property`

Since these things worked before, is there any way to solve them without adding kernel parameters or creating a custom xorg.conf? Has anybody else experienced these problems?

Comment: The problem persists with the new 4.6.4 kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the Lenovo Firmware (latest version is N1CET46W (1.14)). You can check by command:

```
sudo dmidecode -s bios-version
```

New firmware should help.